# How to check browser support ajax or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.12 . But my question is how to check browser support ajax or not. If browser support ajax then i want to change page content using ajax.

Comment: `if (true) { /*...browser supports ajax...*/ }` And of course, since the condition is an invariant, you can remove the `if`.

Answer (score 4):

Almost every browser now support AJAX.

If you still want to test it you can check for `XMLHttpRequest`

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

     // Supports Ajax.

    } else {

     //No. 
}
```

Comment: @hime: Beware that this test will fail on old IE, but jQuery v1.12 still supports ajax on old IE. The point of my comment on the question was: I'm not aware of **any** browser of any significance in the modern world that doesn't suport ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   <!-- 

   function ajaxFunction(){
      var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

      try{
         // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari (1st attempt)
         ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }catch (e){
         // IE browser (2nd attempt)
         try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e) {
            try{
         // 3rd attempt
               ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){

               alert("Failure");
               return false;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   //-->
   </script>
```

Try individually three times to make the XMLHttpRequest object.
If all cases fail, it is sure that the browser is outdated and doesn't support ajax. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Found this at: http://programmerguru.com/ajax-tutorial/browser-support/

```
Here is the code snippet which checks if the browser supports AJAX or not.
?
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function checkAJAXSupport() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
      alert("Yes. Your browser must be one among them - Mozilla, Safari, Chrome, Rockmelt, IE 8.0 or above");
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        alert("Yes. Your browser must be IE");
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          alert("Yes. Your browser must be IE");
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }
 if (!xmlhttp) {
      alert("No. Giving up Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance. Your browser is outdated!");
      return false;
    }
}
</script>
```